# kubectl exec/logs on EKS returns "remote error: tls: internal error"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

Both Logs/ Exec commands are throwing tls error:

```
$ kubectl logs <POD-NAME>

Error from server: Get "https://<NODE-PRIVATE-IP>:10250/containerLogs/<NAMESPACE>/<POD-NAME>/<DEPLOYMENT-NAME>": remote error: tls: internal error
```

```
$ kubectl exec -it <POD-NAME> -- sh

Error from server: error dialing backend: remote error: tls: internal error
```

Comment: kubectl auth issue check the config of your cluster and cert with proxy if using

Comment: @HarshManvar I checked aws-auth it is configured with the cluster role

Answer (score 2):

Check if your hostname type setting in the subnet and launch template configuration is using resource name and if that is the case then switch to using IP name instead. I think this is caused by some weird pattern matching going on with the AWS EKS control plane (as of v1.22) where it would not issue a certificate for a node if that node's hostname doesn't match its requirements. You can test this quickly by adding another node group to your cluster with the nodes' hostnames set to IP name.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my cluster configured official documentation from AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/service_IAM_role.html and looks like following section doesn't work:

```
    "Condition": {
      "ArnLike": {
        "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:eks:region-code:your-account-id:cluster/cluster-name"
      }
    }
```

Try removing this and restart containers.